# Is an iteration on a F# map or set in-order traversal?

Tags: f#, dictionary, iteration, set

AFAIK, F# Map and set are implemented as red-black trees, so I guess that an iteration on these would be in-order traversal. I did some test and the iteration results are always sorted. But I want to make it sure.

Is it in-order traversal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation on MSDN is pretty good for figuring this out.  For instance, the return value for [`Set.toSeq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353561.aspx) is "An ordered sequence of the elements of set."  It looks like the answer to your question is yes, for both maps and sets.

Comment: Oh, thnx, I am silly. I was looking up the document of the Map Class only, not the Map Module.

Answer (score 4):

> AFAIK, F# Map and set are implemented as red-black trees

AVL trees.

> Is it in-order traversal?

Yes.