# f# set and map equality

Tags: dictionary, f#, set, equality

How does `set1 = set2` for F# immutable sets and maps work? Will they do proper set/map equality?

The documentation says:

> Immutable sets based on binary trees, where comparison is the F#
>   structural comparison function, potentially using implementations of
>   the IComparable interface on key values.

They are based on binary trees, so might not the exact form depending on the order elements were inserted? So naively using the F# structural comparison function would not work...

I can't find anything about it in the documentation. Have I just missed it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it will work properly, apparently.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs#L710), `Equals` is overridden and uses `GetEnumerator` and checks that these return the same elements in the same order. These should be in-order as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977837/is-an-iteration-on-a-f-map-or-set-in-order-traversal), since the doc for `Set.toSeq` says: "An ordered sequence of the elements of set."

This is also mentioned in the book "F# for Scientists" by Jon Harrop and Don Syme:

[image: quote from "F# for Scientists"]